# how to auto-refresh AWS STS token when it expires while accessing Amazon EKS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-iam, amazon-eks, kubernetes-apiserver

I get temp token using STS-AssumeRole, then I use the token to construct k8s apiClient and CoreV1Api:

```
ApiClient apiClient = new ClientBuilder()
                                .setAuthentication(new AccessTokenAuthentication(token))
                                .setBasePath(endpointUrl)
                                .setCertificateAuthority(cacert)
                                .setVerifyingSsl(true)
                                .build();

CoreV1Api api = new CoreV1Api(apiClient);

V1PodList podList = api.listPodForAllNamespaces(null, null, labelSelector, null, null, null, null, null);
```

I call listPodForAllNamespaces every few minutes. However, token expires in 1 hour. How can I update tokens in ApiClient?

Token construction is the same as this: [Get authentication token from AWS EKS using the AWS Java SDK v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59853623/get-authentication-token-from-aws-eks-using-the-aws-java-sdk-v2).
And I hava seen [how to auto-refresh AWS STS Temporary security credentials when it expires while accessing Amazon SQS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68947757/how-to-auto-refresh-aws-sts-temporary-security-credentials-when-it-expires-while), however, apiclient doesn't have the Credentials parameter.